# How to determine a proper serial version ID?

Tags: java, serialization

How to determine a proper serial version ID? Should it be any big long value using some generators or any integer wld suffice ?

Comment: OK my question was more of what makes a good serialVersionUID. Why can't I just initialize with 1 , than going through the cumbersome process og generating it.

Comment: You can start at 1, as long as you remember to increment it manually any time it needs to change. Or you can let your IDE or even your JRE generate it for you. The trick is to ensure it changes precisely every time it needs to, and no more frequently than that. IDE generation is a reasonable compromise, but a check-in trigger in your SCM system would be even better...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Frankly, as long as the `serialVersionUID` differs between the different versions of your class, that's all that matters.

What would be bad is if there are two versions of the same class with differing serializable fields having the same `serialVersionUID` -- that's probably going to cause a problem when performing serialization.

Additionally, if the changes to the class will not affect serialization (e.g. serializable fields in the class remain the same), then the `serialVersionUID` can remain the same.

IDEs like Eclipse will automatically generate an ID for classes which implement `Serializable` based on the fields and other information regarding the class, so that may be the easiest route to take to generate an unique ID.

For further reading on the topic, the [Discover the secrets of the Java Serialization API](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/) would be a good read. There is a section called "Version Control" which discusses the `serialVersionUID` issue.

Answer (score 2):

The serialver tool comes with Sun's Java Development Kit (JDK). It takes a full class name on the command line and returns the serial version ID for that compiled class, or can be run with the "-show" parameter to launch a small interactive GUI.

So if your class is Foo, run

serialver Foo

and you'll get some sort of output like this:

Foo:    static final long serialVersionUID = -6618469841127325812L;

Take the code starting with "static" and place it inside your class with other static variables. Now the serial version ID is locked in the class.

Answer (score 2):

Possible uses:

- version - increment it when the class changes in an incompatible way;
- timestamp - set it to the current timestamp - e.g. `200906121213` when the class changes in an incompatible way.

Comment: what does your second point mean ? setting it to timestamo  makes it incompatible? or is it not proper practice.

Comment: Sorry : then -> when . Will fix.

Answer (score 1):

start command prompt

type below :

cd\

then type below

**[serialver][space]-classpath[space][path of your class file][space][class file name]**

e.g.

**serialver -classpath C:\Users\nileshjadav\Documents\java\file_io ByteStreamDemo**

please do not add extension like ByteStreamDemo.java or ByteStreamDemo.class simply used just ByteStreamDemo

Answer (score -1):

Adding to the answer few things to take care before generating serialVersionUID using java serialver utility.

1. JDK path till bin to be set in environment variables. Other wise you may get "'serialver' is not recognized as an internal or external command".
2. Add class path where your class file is located or go to the directory where your class file is there.
3. run serialver .. This will give you SerialID.
4. Class name pass to this utility does not include .class extension.

Comment: Observation: For a given class serial ID remains the same till we do not change the class. Generating it from eclipse will also give you the same result.